# Проблема с изменением текста QPushButton при помощи sender() в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Проблема при попытке получить сигналы от нажатия на кнопку.
Есть **`2`** кнопки, при нажатии на которые должен меняться текст этой кнопки (сработать метод cross() , но программа просто крашится.

Как это можно исправить?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(250, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 71, 71))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border: none")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.cross)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 0, 71, 71))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border: none")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.cross)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

    def cross(self):
        self.sender().setText('x')
        self.sender().setFont(QFont('Times', 50))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы используете объект self.sender но не где его не создаёте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(250, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 71, 71))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border: none")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 0, 71, 71))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border: none")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #ccffbd;}')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.cross)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.cross)

    def cross(self):
        self.sender().setText('x')
        self.sender().setFont(QFont('Times', 50))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]